# Trying to push new key/value pair to array not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to push the first and last initial of a user to an object array of my users contact information using angular.forEach and I'm not doing it right.

Here is the code I have:

```
var firstInit = '';
var lastInit = '';

angular.forEach(self.contacts, function(value, key){
  firstInit = key.first_name.charAt(0);
  lastInit = key.last_name.charAt(0);
  this.push(firstInit + ':' + lastInit);
});
```

But I'm getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined

Any advice?

Update:

I changed the code to the following and now I can get the values, but when I try to push onto the contacts object, I'm getting "push" is not a function. Though if I take away the "key" I can push the initials, but they are on the root of the array and not where I want them to be in each object.

Here is the code:

```
var firstInit = '';
var lastInit = '';

angular.forEach(self.contacts, function(value, key){

    firstInit = self.contacts[key].first_name.charAt(0);
    lastInit = self.contacts[key].last_name.charAt(0);

    self.contacts[key].push(firstInit + lastInit);

});
```

Comment: plz post the code where you declared and/or manipulated `first_name` and `last_name`.

Comment: put a `console.log(key.first_name)` before you assign value to `firstInit`, most probably `key.first_name` in `undefined`

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined` means that `key.first_name` is undefined. `key` is probably a string and not an object.

Comment: `self.contacts` is the array, and will have the `push` function on it. `self.contacts[key]` is an item in the array, and won't have the `push` function. Please read up [about Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score 0):

Either `key.first_name` or `key.last_name` is undefined in your contacts somewhere. This is a possible solution:

```
var firstInit = '';
var lastInit = '';

angular.forEach(self.contacts, function(value, key){
  if (key.first_name)
    firstInit = key.first_name.charAt(0);
  if (key.last_name)
    lastInit = key.last_name.charAt(0);
  this.push(firstInit + ':' + lastInit);
});
```

Comment: No prob. What exactly are you trying to do with the initials? It looks like you are trying to push them back on top of the array you got them from, just in a different index. What's your goal here? And it might help to know what each contacts object looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fix:

```
var inits = '';
var newContacts = [];

angular.forEach(self.contacts, function(value, key){
  console.log(value.first_name);
  inits = self.contacts[key].first_name.charAt(0) + self.contacts[key].last_name.charAt(0);
  value.userInitials = inits;
  newContacts.push(value);
});
```

Alternatively, I could have just used "value" instead of getting the index/key. That got me the name  fields. I created a new object array and pushed the value. I added the  new key/value pair with dot notation.